# java hibernate override enum/string mapping values

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, mapping

I've got a following Hibernate model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private CategoryType type;
```

This is the enumeration referenced by hibernate:

```
public enum CategoryType {
    INCOME, OUTCOME;
}
```

THe corresponding database field is a varchar which takes 2 possible values: "CategoryIncome" and "CategoryOutcome".

This method actually calls hibernate:

```
public List<Category> findAllByType(CategoryType type) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery(
        "FROM Category WHERE type = :type");
    query.setParameter("type", type);
    List list = query.list();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return list;
}
```

I managed to get my code work (I mean it compiles), but it works badly - it executes following SQL query:

```
WHERE type = "INCOME"
```

whereas I would like it to be:

```
WHERE type = "CategoryIncome"
```

How can I map enum values into string values for hibernate? I know that `EnumType.STRING` tells hibernate to cast the enum values to string (could be EnumType.ORDINAL to cast it to integers). But how can I override the default enum-string mapping?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use your customized usertype for Hibernate persistance, Hibernate uses `name()` function of `enum` to get string representation, not `toString()`.

See this
[Hibernate @Enumerated mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450902/hibernate-enumerated-mapping)