# Hibernate: mapping enum with dash

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I have a column in database with 5 possible values. I want to map this column as an enum field. The problem is some of these values contain a dash. I tried something like this:

```
public enum Status {
    S1("S1"), S2("S2"), S3("S-3"), S4("S-4"), S5("S5");

    private final String text;

    Status(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.text;
    }
```

But it doesn't work. If the row in database contains value with a dash, I get an error:

```
Unknown name value [S-3] for enum class [test.package.Status]
```

Is there any way to map values containing dash to an enum?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping enum to a table with hibernate annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735732/mapping-enum-to-a-table-with-hibernate-annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toString() do not work as the evaluation of enum is based on `public final String name()`. And as this is final you can not override it.

You will have to use another type. [In this answer you will get the required info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450902/hibernate-enumerated-mapping)

Answer (score 0):

have u tried this one in your model

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Status status

Comment: Yes and it works for other enums, but for this one with dashes it fails.

Comment: This will fail. As you need to have same values in DB as enum.